# How to write this math equations without $

Tags: equations, math-operators

Does anyone know how to write these equations without $?

[image]QFtHB.jpg

Comment: `\( ... \)` maybe?

Comment: What do you mean "without `$`"? Are you talking about the math markup of (La)TeX? If so, why would you want to do this outside of "math mode"? Perhaps if one understands your motivation better, one could provide more appropriate solutions.

Comment: thanks but I've tried the \(.....\) but in combination with the align didn't work.I use align because I want numbering the equations.what else can i do?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Would any environment such as 'align' or 'equation' or 'gather' would be fine for you?

\begin{equation}
A = B
\end {equation}

Comment: @Renia: `align` already initiates math mode, so there's no need for `$` inside it...

Comment: I know that but when I use align this those types there is an error :but math environment delimiter.what is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
g\Bigl(x\mathrel{\Big|}\mu_i,\sum_i\Bigr) = {}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^D |\sum_i|}} \exp\biggl(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_i)^{'} \notag \\
                                              & \times\sum_i^{-1}(x-\mu_i)\biggr),
\end{align}

\[H_2 = \sum_\Omega^{} \log(|B(f_k,f_k)|)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To number the second equation and align the two `=` signs (and thanks to @Mico for correcting the notation for the binomial distribution):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
g(x\mathrel{|}\mu_i,\Sigma_i^{}) 
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^D |\Sigma_i|}} \exp\Bigl(-\frac12(x-\mu_i)^{'}\notag \\
    &  \phantom{={}} \times\Sigma_i^{-1}(x-\mu_i)\Bigr),\\
H_2 &= \sum_\Omega^{} \log(|B(f_k,f_k)|)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @AboAmmar!Is there any way to numbering and the second equation?

Comment: @Renia  - Yes, but how would you like it to be aligned? left aligned like your image or centered like my image?

Comment: if the second equation is to be numbered, include it in the `align`.  a better approach to getting just one number for the first two lines is to use either `split` or `aligned` within the `align`.  and it's very bad practice to treat adjacent display formulas separately;  they should be grouped within a multi-line structure such as `align` or `gather`.  please refer to the `amsmath` documentation -- `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: @AboAmmar like yours!

Comment: Put it like this: `\begin{equation}
H_2 = \sum_\Omega^{} \log(|B(f_k,f_k)|)
\end{equation}` Or see the update

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what i meant.you are the best!

Comment: @Mico ok! that sounds right to me.spread the word!

Comment: @Mico - Thank you, I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &g\Bigl(x \mathrel{\Big\vert} \mu_i,∑_i\Bigr) ={} & &\frac{1}{√{(2π)^D}\lvert∑_i\rvert}\exp\biggl(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_i)' \\[-1ex]
    & & & × ∑_i^{-1 } (x-\mu_i)\biggr),\\
    & H₂ = {} \mathrlap{∑_{Ω}\log()\lvert B(f_k, f_k)\rvert)}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]